# Finding the minimal value in any range of an arbitrary array in log time complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Given an array of numbers, **and allowing processing in `O(n)`**, I'd like a data structure/algorithm to be able to find the minimal element in any given range of the array in logarithmic time.

One solution I've seen is processing the array by storing it in a nearly complete binary tree (by index, in order), and adding an additional field to each node to include the minimal element in the node's subtree - it works, though actually finding the minimal element in a range becomes fairly complicated.

Is there a neater solution?

Comment: There's a wikipedia page on this problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query

Comment: It sounds like you've already found the solution -- a range query tree -- and want something easier. I don't think there's anything easier (and a RQT is actually not so difficult to implement from scratch).

Comment: I think you are looking for the Cartesian tree. The Wikipedia entry suggested by Paul Hanking mentions it. But in case you missed it, it has its own Wikipedia entry.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question, because the tree solution that you're complaining about is usually considered to be pretty clean and easy.  Maybe you're imagining some complicated way of doing it...

But I'm going to take this at face value and try to make it really as simple as possible.

I'll write the query function first:

```
func rangeMinimum(lo, hi):
    lo+=offset
    hi+=offset
    minval = MAX_VALUE
    while(lo<=hi):
        if (lo%2 == 1):
            minval = min(minval, array[lo++])
        else if (hi%2 == 0):
            minval = min(minval, array[hi--])
        else
            lo/=2
            hi/=2
   return minval
```

Now we just have to make it work.  This is a lot like the complete-tree-in-an-array solution, except that we refuse to deal with any complications caused by leaves at different levels.  This will force us to waste a bit of space.  Still O(n), though.

Every element `array[i]` with i>0 has a "parent" at `array[i/2]`, and in our query function we have been careful to move up to checking the "parent row" by dividing `lo` and `hi` by 2 only when the parent range exactly covers the child range.

We just have to set up `array` and `offset` so that the rows don't overlap and each parent has the minimum value of its children:

```
func setup(origArray):
    offset = 1
    while(offset < origArray.length):
        offset*=2
    array = new int[offset+origArray.length]

    // the last row has the original array
    for (i = 0 until origArray.length):
        array[offset+i] = origArray[i]

    // initialize parents
    for (i = (offset+origArray.length-2)/2 down to 0):
        array[i] = min(array[i*2], array[i*2+1])
```

That's it -- I think that's just about as easy as supporting O(log n) queries can get.